# What is the font used on the Sci-Fi stack exchange page?

Tags: font-identification

The font used on the [Sci-Fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) stack exchange site is pretty cool looking. Is this an available font, or was it most likely created just for that site?

[image: Font image]

Comment: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Orbitron

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Orbitron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrbitronMedium by way of Inspecting Element.

Comment: +1 For awesomely simple method :) I do that all the time(in-fact, a always chose my fonts be looking at other peoples websites :P, since I HATE typography)